# bosun and telegraf metrics meta information

Tags: monitoring, opentsdb, bosun, telegraf

hello i really want to use bosun/tsdbrelay/opentsdb with the telegraf collector, as it gets all the metrics we want to monitor out of the box.
i allready have a small setup to push metrics from 5 servers to bosun for indexing and opentsdb for storage.

i used the haproxy configs from kyle brandts bosun infrastructure blog to make the tsdbs ha-ready

but bosun is showing that it cannot use the auto-type for metrics, and also in the primary stats view does not show any graphs for cpu / mem etc.

what can i provide that the graphs show up.

kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these features are mostly scollector specific. The "host" view (I've considered ripping that out, it was done in the early days, better to use something like grafana) depends on scollector specific metrics such as `os.cpu`.

As far as "Auto" for rate vs gauge, that is also metadata that comes from scollector and sent to bosun. If you want to try to mimic the behavior see https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/blob/master/metadata/metadata.go#L30 and https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/blob/master/metadata/metadata.go#L195 - you would need to create at least the "rate" key for each metric you are getting from telegraph.